# Register a 32 bit dll on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have 32-bit  DLL which was registered on Windows Server 2000. Now, we are process of upgrading it to 64 bit windows server 2012 so i want to use this DLL on the new server.

I tried using 32-bit tools (c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe) to register them to registry. I also made sure the entry exist in registry (using syswow64\regedit32.exe) at HKey_Classes_Root\Wow6432Node\CLSID[GUID] with AppID registered with DLL GUID and DLLSurrogate is enabled at HKey_Classes_Root\Wow6432Node\AppID[GUID]

I also made sure i have enabled 32-bit applications on the Application Pool inside the IIS.

But when i run the code, In my code where it is trying to create a com object for the dll, it sits there executing with a timeout error.

Can anyone please help what can i do/add to make this working. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to register them? Why don't you just place the DLL where the the consuming application can reference it, such as the bin folder?

Comment: It is a third party dll which is compiled by some one else. SO i want to register this on the new windows server 2012 which is a 64 bit machine.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why you want to put it in the GAC. Why now just distribute it in the bin folder of your web application?